# What does (Node)nodes.get(j)) means in the Graph file?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Please find the following files (1) Node 2)Main 3) Graph) attached here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/at9u2684k345uv0/dK77w58rEM

BAsically I'm implementing BFS and DFS and have some questions regarding some code in Graph File:

```
private Node getUnvisitedChildNode(Node n)
{

    int index=nodes.indexOf(n);
    int j=0;
    while(j<size)
    {
        if(adjMatrix[index][j]==1 && ((Node)nodes.get(j)).visited==false)
        {
            return (Node)nodes.get(j);
        }
        j++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Could anyone tell me what does

```
(Node)nodes.get(j))
```

means here?

I have few more Questions:

In bfs() method in the Graph class, I have following Questions:

1) As I understood that

```
"Queue<Node> q=new LinkedList<Node>();"
```

means LinkList implements a Queue.

So, why LinkedList is required in this case, can't we just do it via "Queue q = new Queue();" ?

2) Although I have read the usage of "this" keyword many times, could anyone please explain why

q.add(this.rootNode) is used and why not just q.add(rootNode) ?

3) What does the following line signifies ?

```
while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(n))!=null)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `Graph` class, you'll see this declaration:

```
public ArrayList nodes = new ArrayList();
```

This uses the `ArrayList` type, but isn't using generics (which, by the way, is a Bad Idea).  The line of code

```
((Node)nodes.get(j)).visited
```

Means the following:

1. Get the `j`th element of the `nodes` `ArrayList`.  Since the `ArrayList` is used without generics, this returns an object of type `Object`.
2. Cast that object to a `Node`, which is what that object really is.
3. Look up the `visited` field within that `Node`.

In other words, this means "look up the `Node` stored at position `j` in the `nodes` list, then read its `visited` field.

All of this could easily be avoided if the author used generics with the `ArrayList`, as in

```
public ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

If this were the case, the code to look up a node and read its `visited` field would just be

```
nodes.get(j).visited
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually I'm using generics only in my Eclipse IDE and removing (Nodes) makes sense and increases the clarity of the code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So In other way, considering Generics and the code "nodes.get(j).visited ", it means that :
1) Get the jth element of the nodes arraylist and check whether the visited boolean variable is false or not.